# Python pandas merge dataframes on time column unexpected result

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I want to merge two pandas dataframes by identical time columns:

```
                   Time  g41ko_fuell_hires
0  2021-02-25 19:09:637             120.34
1  2021-02-25 19:09:737             120.46
2  2021-02-25 19:09:837             120.44
3  2021-02-25 19:09:937             120.31
4  2021-02-25 19:09:037             120.35
(308329, 2)

                   Time  g42ko_fuell_hires
0  2021-02-25 19:09:637             118.95
1  2021-02-25 19:09:737             118.94
2  2021-02-25 19:09:837             118.95
3  2021-02-25 19:09:937             118.90
4  2021-02-25 19:09:037             118.85
(308329, 2)
```

I call pd.merge as follows

```
df_final = pd.merge(dfs[0],dfs[1],on='Time',how='inner')
```

What I get is

```
        Time  g41ko_fuell_hires  g42ko_fuell_hires
0    2021-02-25 19:09:637             120.34             118.95
1    2021-02-25 19:09:637             120.34             118.71
2    2021-02-25 19:09:637             120.34             119.90
3    2021-02-25 19:09:637             120.34             119.70
4    2021-02-25 19:09:637             120.34             119.25
...                        ...                ...                ...
18318296  2021-02-26 03:43:971             119.42             119.55
18318297  2021-02-26 03:43:971             119.42             119.76
18318298  2021-02-26 03:43:971             119.42             120.15
18318299  2021-02-26 03:43:971             119.42             120.29
18318300  2021-02-26 03:43:971             119.42             120.50

[1000 rows x 3 columns]
(18318301, 3)
```

So obviously the first entry of the first dataframe is repeated like a cross product. I wanted to have finally 308329 rows with two data columns per row.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 308329**2 is about 10^11 which is  a lot larger than your result. You may want to check how unique the Time is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error.

Time column look like time but was object (additionally malformed due to wrong export from grafana: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS` was needed).

So I needed to convert the time colum by

```
df0['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df0['Time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Than all is ok.